# Apache mod_rewrite/mod_proxy - re-write last part of URI as query string?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

We have a web resource that can be accessed with a URL/URL of the form:

`http://[host1]:[port1]/aaa/bbb.ccc?param1=xxx&param2=yyy...`

However, we are working with an external (i.e., not developed by us, so not under our control, i.e., we can't change it) client app that is attempting to access our resource with a URL that looks like:

`http://[host2]/[port2]/ddd/fff/param1=xxx&param2=yyy...`

In other words, the client is including the "query string" (the `?param1=xxx&param2=yyy...` part) as if it's part of the URI, instead of as a proper query string.

We have a separate Apache proxy instance, and we're thinking that we could use that with some RewriteCond/RewriteRule to take the incoming requests (the ones with the query string at the end of the "URI", and without the "?") and rewrite the URI to a "proper" URI with a "proper" query string and then use that modified/re-written URI to access our resource via proxy.

We'd also like to do that without having an HTTP re-direct (e.g., 30x) going back to the client, because it appears that they may not be able to handle such a re-direct.

I've been trying various things, but I'm not that familiar with Apache mod_rewrite, so I was wondering if someone could tell me (1) if this is possible and (2) suggest what RewriteCond/RewriteRule would accomplish this?

P.S.  I have gotten some progress.  The following re-writes the URL correctly, but when I test, I'm seeing a 302 redirect to the re-written URL, instead of Apache just proxying immediately to the re-written URL.  Is it possible to do this without the re-direct (302)?

```
<Location /test/users/>
RewriteEngine           on
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/param1=
RewriteRule             ^/(.*)/param1=(.*) http://192.168.0.xxx:yyyy/aaa/bbbbb.ccc?base=param1=$2
</Location>
```

Thanks, Jim

Comment: Uggh!  I'm still getting use to the formatting here :(....  Those two example URL templates I included should (obviously) have [host1]:[port1] and [host2]:[port2] in them :)...

Comment: I was able to get the last piece of the puzzle, the immediate proxying instead of redirecting, working.  I had to add a "[P]" at the end of the RewriteRule, and then no more 302/re-direct, and it's working!!

Jim

Comment: This should not be migrated to webmasters: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/328/the-mod-rewrite-problem (How questions do not belong there).  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81032/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so . Jeff's take on mod_rewrite/htaccess: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/apache-configuration-htaccess-questions-esp-mod-rewrite-so-or-sf/34275#34275

Comment: I closed and re-opened this to prevent it being migrated.